# Increase registry value size limit

Tags: windows, winapi, registry, size

I am using Windows 7.

I use `RegSetValueEx()` to write values to registry keys. Today I mentioned that sometimes it returns `0x5AA`, which means `ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES`. I found that buffer size is more than 1Mb; if I reduce it to 1Mb, problem disappears.

I looked into MSDN and see that there are limits: 1Mb in standard format and "available memory" in latest format. But no explanation about these formats was given.

So, the question is: can I write values larger than 1Mb? What does "latest format" mean - is it available in latest Windows versions or I can change it in Windows 7?

Comment: That much data should be saved to a disk file, not the registry.

Comment: MSDN says exactly the same. But I want know if there is a possibility to save large amounts of data in registry.

Comment: *Standard Format* is only Win2k - except for HKCU which is always in this format on all versions of Windows.  As clearly stated by MSFT, don't save large values in the registry, perhaps if you explained *why* you want to do this alternatives can be suggested.

Comment: So I can save large values in HKLM only? Ok, I will use files.